# How to check if a type is a specialization of the std::array class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, type-traits

Is it possible to check that type `T` is an `std::array` of arbitrary type and size?

I can check for a particular array, for instance:

```
is_same<T, std::array<int,5>>::value
```

But I'd like to check that `T` is any instantiation of `std::array`. Something like below (which, of course, does not compile):

```
is_same<T, std::array>::value
```

Is there a way to achieve this (maybe not using `is_same`)?

Comment: You can write a generic `is_same_template` and say `is_same_template <T::template array, std::array>` . The compiler must support the c++11 injected class name rules though.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to write your own, but it's simple:

```
template<typename>
struct is_std_array : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_std_array<std::array<T,N>> : std::true_type {};
```