# C++ Template specialization, decltype, const types, and std::remove_const

Tags: c++, templates

I have been trying to find a way to check whether a variable is a std::array at compile-time. I found the following thread which seems to do this: [How to check if a type is a specialization of the std::array class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905359/how-to-check-if-a-type-is-a-specialization-of-the-stdarray-class-template).

However, I'm getting some strange results to do with `const std::array`s. See the following example:

```
#include <array>

template<typename>
struct is_std_array : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_std_array<std::array<T,N>> : std::true_type {};

std::array<int, 5> nonConstArray = {};
const std::array<int, 5> constArray = {};
constexpr std::array<int, 5> constExprArray = {};

// succeeds - makes sense
static_assert(is_std_array<std::array<int, 5>>::value, "Assertion 1."); 

// also succeeds
static_assert(is_std_array<decltype(nonConstArray)>::value, "Assertion 2."); 
// fails - ??? (how does remove_const affect this when this passed before?)
static_assert(is_std_array<std::remove_const<decltype(nonConstArray)>>::value, "Assertion 3."); 

// fails - ??? - maybe because type is const?
static_assert(is_std_array<decltype(constArray)>::value, "Assertion 4."); 
// fails - ??? - shouldn't the type with const removed work?
static_assert(is_std_array<std::remove_const<decltype(constArray)>>::value, "Assertion 5.");

// fails
static_assert(is_std_array<decltype(constExprArray)>::value, "Assertion 6."); 
// fails
static_assert(is_std_array<std::remove_const<decltype(constExprArray)>>::value, "Assertion 7.");
```

It seems to me like assertions 3, 5 and 7 should pass. Perhaps also 4 and 6. Can anyone shed any light on why these fail?

Comment: `std::remove_const<T>` is a type. You want `std::remove_const_t<T>`.

Comment: You want `std::remove_const<decltype(nonConstArray)>::type` or `std::remove_const_t<decltype(nonConstArray)>` (the latter is an alias for the former).

Comment: I see. What exactly is the difference between remove_const and remove_const_t? When should one be used vs the other?

Comment: always use the `_t` or `_v` type trait

Comment: `remove_const  will return a struct that has a `type` member (this struct is part of the meta template programming implementation), `remove_const_t` will be equal to that `type` member

Comment: See [What does a class followed by _t (underscore-t) in typename statement represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943284/what-does-a-class-followed-by-t-underscore-t-in-typename-statement-represent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone shed any light on why these fail?

Basically because since you're not using the suffix `_t`, you're getting a **class type** like `std::remove_const<...>` which is different from the class type `std::array<...>`.

---

Let's look at one of the examples.

```
static_assert(is_std_array<std::remove_const<decltype(nonConstArray)>>::value, "Assertion 3.");
```

Here `decltype(nonConstArray)` gives us the type `std::array<int, 5>` so that `std::remove_const<decltype(nonConstArray)>` is also a **class type** `std::remove_const<std::array<int, 5> >` which will fail the next test `is_std::array`.

##### Solution

To actually get the `std::array<...>` class type you'll need to access/***use the type member*** by adding the suffix `_t` to `std::remove_const`as shown below.

```
//------------------------------------------vv-------> this _t suffix has been added 
static_assert(is_std_array<std::remove_const_t<decltype(nonConstArray)>>::value, "Assertion 3.");
```

---

The same goes for your other examples.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, this has been helpful.